# NSData initWithContentsOfURL stuck app running on iphone 4s

Tags: nsdata

When running on the simulater and on 4G iphone evering works great.

trying to init NSData with a spesific image from url stuck the app when i try to run it on iphone 4S

[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:

anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was probably a problem with the image...

changing the image link slved the problem